# Use of file:// type links in RSS feeds

Tags: rss

I want to create a RSS feed for a Windows network folder (something like `//acme/test`).

In the `<link>` element I tried the following options, but to no success:

1. `<link>file:////acme/test</link>`
2. `<link>file://\\acme\test</link>`
3. `<link>\\acme\test</link>`

Any ideas? I am using RSS 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to follow [the RSS 2.0 specs, you're going to have a bit of a problem](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html#comments) as it's not really one of the supported or valid link types:

> RSS places restrictions on the first non-whitespace characters of the data in `<link>` and `<url>` elements. The data in these elements must begin with an IANA-registered URI scheme, such as http://, https://, news://, mailto: and ftp://. Prior to RSS 2.0, the specification only allowed http:// and ftp://, however, in practice other URI schemes were in use by content developers and supported by aggregators. Aggregators may have limits on the URI schemes they support. Content developers should not assume that all aggregators support all schemes.

So if you need it to work with those network folder links, you'll need an aggregator that can handle it, or write one yourself.

Comment: The provided link wouldn't resolve for me. I did, however, find an identical reference that contains the quoted material at http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#comments . In my case, I wanted to know whether RSS 2.0 permits the use of a **relative URL** for the value of a `link` element. According to the specification, it appears ***not***.